# What is a Hebbian linear classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, papers, hebbian-learning

I was reading [Deep Learning of Representations for Unsupervised and Transfer Learning](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228618750_Deep_learning_of_representations_for_unsupervised_and_transfer_learning),
and they state the following:

> They have only a small number of unlabeled examples (4096) and very few labeled examples (1
> to 64 per class) available to a Hebbian linear classifier (which discriminates according to
> the median between the centroids of two classes compared) applied separately to each class
> against the others.

I have searched about what a Hebbian linear classifier is, but I couldn't find more than an explanation about what Hebbian learning is, so can anybody explain what Hebbian linear classifier is?